# Managing a SQLite Database Connection

Tags: c#, sqlite

When the application connects to the database it keeps the connection open until the user closes the file using File->Close.

Is this bad practice?

Should I be opening and closing the connection every time I need to use it?

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace timelord
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Manages the tasks database
    /// </summary>
    class Timesheet
    {
        private string filePath;
        private SQLiteConnection sqlite;
        private SQLiteDataAdapter adapter;
        private SQLiteCommandBuilder builder;
        private DataTable datatable;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a timesheet object that determines if the filepath exists.
        /// If the filepath exists then it opens a database.
        /// If it does not exist it creates a database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">The path to open or create a database file at.</param>
        public Timesheet(string filePath)
        {
            this.filePath = filePath;

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                openDatabase();

            }else
            {
                createDatabase();

                createSchema();
            }

            prepareQueries();

            this.datatable = new DataTable();

            this.adapter.Fill(this.datatable);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls the methods that create the database file, connection, and schema
        /// </summary>
        private void createDatabase()
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(filePath);

            openDatabase();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the database connection
        /// </summary>
        private void openDatabase()
        {
            sqlite = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + this.filePath + ";Version=3;");
            try
            {
                sqlite.Open();
            }
            catch(SQLiteException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the schema for all tables nessicary
        /// </summary>
        private void createSchema()
        {
            string query = "CREATE TABLE task (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, description TEXT, begindate TEXT, enddate TEXT, status INTEGER default 0)";

            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, sqlite);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prepares the queries used to manipulate the timesheet
        /// </summary>
        private void prepareQueries()
        {
            adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select id,description,begindate,enddate,status from task", sqlite);

            builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);

            adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
            adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
            adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return the task table
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public DataTable Tasks()
        {
            return this.datatable;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            adapter.Update(datatable);

            datatable.Clear();

            adapter.Fill(datatable);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Closes the database connection
        /// </summary>
        public void close()
        {
            sqlite.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question. But MS `EntityFramework` will be your good friend about managing database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10460418/648075

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to create the database file if it doesn't exist, the `SQLite` driver will take care of it; to ensure your table does not exist on creation, you can just add `IF NOT EXISTS` to the query.

I would also close the connection every time, this has already been covered by other answers. In addition I would make the class stateless as it doesn't need a state if we open/close the connection every time (Being stateless brings a lot of other advantages).

I would also remove any logic from the constructor, to do this you will need a state or you will have to check on every command unfortunately so I left it to you.

Here is my 0.02:

```
internal class Timesheet
{
    private const string SelectTaskQuery = "SELECT id, description, begindate, enddate, status FROM task";

    private readonly string _filePath;

    public Timesheet(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;

        InitializeDb();
    }

    private DataTable Tasks() => ExecuteWithConnection(Tasks);

    private void InitializeDb() => ExecuteWithConnection(connection =>
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            CreateSchemaIfNotExists(command);
    });

    private SQLiteConnection GetConnection() => new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + _filePath + ";Version=3;");

    private void ExecuteWithConnection(Action<SQLiteConnection> action)
    {
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();

            action(connection);
        }
    }

    private T ExecuteWithConnection<T>(Func<SQLiteConnection, T> action)
    {
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();

            return action(connection);
        }
    }

    private static DataTable Tasks(SQLiteConnection connection)
    {
        var adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(SelectTaskQuery, connection);

        var datatable = new DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(datatable);

        return datatable;
    }

    public void Update(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        ExecuteWithConnection(connection =>
        {
            var adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(SelectTaskQuery, connection);

            var builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);

            adapter.Update(dataTable);
        });
    }

    private static void CreateSchemaIfNotExists(IDbCommand command)
    {
        const string query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS task (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, description TEXT, begindate TEXT, enddate TEXT, status INTEGER default 0)";

        command.CommandText = query;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I would also add a small **ORM** like Dapper and add statically typed entities for insert/update.

Comment: Damn this is complicated. I don't know half of these syntaxes.

Comment: Happy to explain if you want to know more about my suggestion. Are you using C# 6?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise With .NET 4.6. How do I check what version of C# I am using?

Comment: VS2015 uses C#6 by default, if you don't restrict it on purpose, you should have the latest language.

Comment: So creating and destroying a database connection constantly is better than creating one and opening and closing it?

Comment: @Ben In short: Yes, but you are not really creating a new connection under the hood as the ADO.NET connection pool will keep your previous ones. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Comment: I can't find much on Action<SQLiteConnection> Action is a delegate and <> makes it generic? But what for?

Comment: @Ben it's a variable to store your intent before executing it with the SQLConnection, it's a great way to avoid duplicate code; a bit of functional programming helps make everything more readable. Basically you pass an action which is what you WOULD do on a SQLConnection and then it is invoked later when the connection is created.

Comment: @Ben have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375166/Functional-programming-in-Csharp

Comment: Could I bug you to rewrite this exact thing without any lambda expressions. Or are they required for delegates?

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure what you are after.

Comment: Why did you not call connection.close() in the ExecuteWithConnection method? If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose. Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent. If the connection pooling value Pooling is set to true or yes, the underlying connection is returned back to the connection pool. On the other hand, if Pooling is set to false or no, the underlying connection to the server is closed.

Comment: @Ben `using` implicitly calls Dispose().

Comment: in the update method you only get the update command. If I delete or insert tasks won't it need the 2 other commands?

Comment: Correct, I think "Update" is a bit confusing as name then. I would call it "Commit" maybe and add the other commands.

Comment: Why is the db handling done via Static class, and not just a non-static class? What is the real gain? I guess non-static is better since objects that need cleaning will be cleaned by framework automatically.

Comment: I'm not with you on this, where is the static class?

Comment: @Stefanod'Antonio this looks great. I _think_ the `Update()` should be done within a transaction too, particularly because SQLite will be very slow when updating lots of rows as it'll create an implicit transaction for each one.

Comment: @Stefanod'Antonio - method `private T ExecuteWithConnection<T>(Func<SQLiteConnection, T> action)` should also open the connection before use.

Comment: @Rory true, must have missed it out

Comment: @Stefanod'Antonio - within `Update()` you don't need to do `adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();` as the builder does that automatically when constructed. (fyi I'm using this great example as a template for something I'm working on, hence the minor suggestions).

Comment: @Rory that was a copy/paste/refactor from the code in the question (I use Dapper for DB access generally so I didn't review API calls, too). But I appreciate your comments, it is always nice to keep improving the code.

Comment: @Rory I removed the line as suggested, but I have a feeling that you have to invoke something on the builder instead. Don't have time to test it now, but I'm happy to update the answer if you want to suggest the change.

Answer (score 3):

Few remarks

1. Try to make your class reusable. For example it cannot be used in web or console application, because it has reference to namespace System.Windows.Forms. Delete it, delete `MessageBox.Show(e.Message);` and let client of your library decide itself how to handle exceptions.
2. There are a lot of general .Net name convention violations ... Here for example `createSchema`. Use `CreateSchema` instead.
3. I would make your class more lazy :). I mean i would not get all data from database in constructor but only when `Tasks` method will be called.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you shouldn't use comments unless you're publishing this as a library or it's very hard to represent what function and classes do by its name.

`CreateDatabase()` or `OpenDatabase()` it's pretty straightfoward it does what its name says so a comment it isn't really useful, unless you have many variations of the same function.

Instead of leaving the connection open you could do this when executing queries:

```
 using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
 {
   using(MysqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Command, con);   
   {
     //Add parameters and execute
   }
 }
```

Besides this I can't see anythin "wrong".

Comment: My college assignments require everything commented so I have a bad habit of making useless comments

Comment: Never mind leaving the connection open, you have forgotten to open it.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a separate class to handle all interactions wit SQL. Preferably a singleton class so I can reuse it. From there you can handle updates by something like passing in list of columns and the values you would like to update, also including the table. It is pretty flexible on how you want to implement it.

I normally just try to apply the rule of re-usability and scalability, also with KISS (keep it simple stupid) lastly DRY (Don't repeat yourself).